# Disable the auto sorting after a column is sorted

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview in c# and when the user sorts on column click it is sorting correctly.  When they enter data the column continually re sorts.  Is there a way to turn off the sorting so the user can add multiple entries and then sort after they are finished?

Tried multiple ways of turning the column sort mode to NotSortable

```
this.dgvSequence.Columns[2].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
```

but nothing seems to stop the column from sorting after the initial sort.

Comment: How is finished defined? A click on a button? GridView loses focus? A computed column in the shown data marking new rows might help when you always sort first by that column. That means you also need custom sorting then.

Comment: The user selects multiple cells to auto generate a number and then clicks another button to write back to a SQL DB.  I had a feeling that I would have to create some kind of custom sorting.  Was just trying to find an easier way.  Thanks for your reply

Comment: My be easier way is  set  this.dgvSequence.Columns[2].SortMode=DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic  and then set this.dgvSequence.Columns[2].SortMode=DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic ; this.dgvSequence.Sort(Columns[2], --direction--)

Answer (score 0):

So you want the sorting to occur ONLY when the operator clicks the header of a column, not if the operator changes data, nor when data is changed for any other reason.

Why not disable automatic sorting of the columns, and add an event handler upon clicking the header of the column. Use event [DataGridView.ColumnHeaderMouseClick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadermouseclick?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

```
private void SortColumn(DataGridViewColumn columnToSort)
{
    // TODO: add the code to do the sorting
}

private void OnColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender,  DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.SortColumn(this.DataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex]);
}
```